# How to change user role setting in members plugin so that user can only edit his own post?

Tags: user-roles, user-access, members

I want enable a user to only edit specific post. I am using the members plugin. I do not see a way to achieve this. Do I need to do some code for that post?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Short and sweet way would be to store the post id that they are allowed to edit in custom user meta. Then us [wp_update_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) and check if the id is in the user meta if so update if not don't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I am trying to combine two plugins to make this way works. Appreciated!

Comment: and thanks for not voting me down lol, for my reputation is low enough as start hehe :)

Comment: To Be honest, I thought about down voting you as this seems like a "Tell me how to do this for free" type question. A suggestion would be to tell us what you've tried what didn't work and other ideas. This encorages the community to then help you though the process.